# Scripting HELP needed for finding LIVE HOSTS using bash in linux

Tags: linux, bash

How do I create a script that will identify all live hosts (responding to ping) using bin/bash in linux?  My thoughts are to first have a

```
fping -A "some URL"  // to get the IP address
```

then to set that to a var.  then run a

```
fping -g "var"   // having the ip address inserted by using a var.
```

Is there an easier way?  If so, what would that script look like?

Comment: The [nmap](http://nmap.org/book/man.html) tool can be used to detect hosts across a range of IPs.

Comment: If I type the following....
fping -A uma.edu
I get...  130.111.60.172 is alive
then I type fping -g 130.111.60/24
I get ...... a lot.

I need to turn that into a script where I can declare the url, then it auto does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do and why you use fping, but if you just need the IP for a host you should use somthing like this:

1. `getent ahostsv4 www.google.de | grep STREAM | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
2. `getent ahostsv6 www.google.de | grep STREAM | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
3. `getent hosts google.de | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`

All commands will resolve an IP address if host still exist. If host points to CNAME it will also get the IP in that case.

Lets say, you have a text file containing all your hosts to test:

like: `test-hosts.txt`

```
www.server1.dom
www.server2.dom
server3.dom
1.3.5.7
```

then the command line (contains bash-script) will do it:

`cat test-hosts.txt | xargs -i\{\} bash -c 'HOST="{}"; IP=$(getent ahostsv4 "{}" | grep STREAM | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 1); ping -c 1 -w 5 "$IP" >/dev/null 2>&1; RESULT="$?"; echo -e "Host: $HOST ($IP) \c"; case "$RESULT" in 0) echo "is online";; 1) echo "not responding after 5 secs";; *) if [[ "$IP" == "" ]]; then echo "has no resolveable address"; else echo "not availabe due to error [$RESULT]"; fi;; esac;'`

and provide outputs like:

1. is online
2. not responding
3. no resolveable address
4. not available due error [code]